# how to edit jMeter include files?

Tags: jmeter

I have inherited a jMeter test script which uses include files, for modularity.   When I have jMeter open the top-level .jmx file, it automatically reads in the "include" files, and the script executes just fine.

Unfortunately I can't convince jMeter to actually display the *contents* of these included files.  Instead, it just displays their pathnames.

For example, the top level script ("DeviceRegistrationStressTest.jmx") includes the file "modules/rda_preparations.jmx", but jMeter will not actually display what is in this "rda_preparations.jmx" file.   Just its pathname.  (Tried to upload a pic, but stackoverflow gave me an error re: needing a 10 reputation to post images).

Any suggestions on how I can get jMeter to show me the contents of "rda_preparations.jmx"?

Answer (score 1):

JMeter test fragments .jmx files editable just like regular JMeter test plans. Use the File->Open dialogue to open the test fragment file to edit it interactively via the GUI.

Once you're done editing it, save it, and then use it in the top level test plan through an Include controller.

Ref:
http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-manage-large-jmeter-scripts-jmeter-test-fragments